# go to the most recent state on clicking the back button

Tags: django, http

Im building a website using django. On my display page, I have a list of items (with the name results), and I have filters which filter "results" and get another list "filtered" on the display page using an ajax call.

Now when I go to some other page, and then click the back button, I get back to the page with the filters selected, but the results are not filtered (I would want the "filters" list rather than the "results" list on going back). How do I get to the most recent state after using the back button? Basically, everything done using javascript and the subsequent actions get flushed.

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browser history behavior gets complex, but one technique I've used is to embed the state in the hash.  That will make the browser treat each different hash value as a different page in the history, and also lets you do things like bookmark a particular filter selection state.  I used jquery, along these lines:

```
$(function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    // parse the hash and update your filter settings, then get the content and display it
  };

  function update_hash() {
    // calculate the hash based on your filter
    window.location.hash = new_hash;
  };

};
```

Then bind update_hash as an event handler for changes.